# How to detect webex meeting or google meeting in progress

Tags: windows, api, detection, webex, google-meet

I would like to automate disabling breaks in [stretchly](https://github.com/hovancik/stretchly) while a webex meeting or google meeting is in progress on my PC. I'm using win10.

Unfortunately, both Webex and google meeting do not spawn a new process when the meeting is in progress. Therefore I need an alternative detection mechanism.

1. A running Webex meeting could be detected via a window with a particular title. Is there another alternative?
2. Google meeting runs in a browser (I use Chrome) and I have not found a simple way to get a list of opened tabs. I looked at network connection but I have not found a simple pattern for detection.

Can you suggest to me other ideas on how to detect running meetings? I don't want to check the calendar because you can start meeting manually.

Thx Vitek